# How to put unique values of 1 series as columns and count each occurence of the unique values from the series per quarter?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df that looks like this:

```
           date                              col1
0      2020-01-09T19:25                      a
1      2020-01-09T13:27                      a
2      2020-01-04T13:44                      b
3      2019-12-31T15:37                      b
4      2019-12-23T21:47                      c
```

I want to assign the unique values of col1 as columns headers and group the dates by quarter and count the unique values of col1 by quarter.

I can groupby quarters and count like so:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) 

df = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('Q'))['col1'].agg(['count'])
```

The df now looks like this:

```
               count
dateresponded       
2019Q4            2
2020Q1            3
```

I cant tell what the count of the unique values are by broken down.

I want the df to look like this:

```
                   a                b               c              
dateresponded       
2019Q4                              1               1
2020Q1             2                1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you want [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
new_df = pd.crosstab(df['date'].dt.to_period('Q'),df['col1'],
                     rownames=['dateresponded'],
                     colnames=[None])
print(new_df)
```

We could also use `groupby` + [`DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).We can rename the axis using [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html).

```
new_df = (df.groupby([df['date'].dt.to_period('Q'),'col1'])
            .size()
            .unstack(fill_value = 0)
            .rename_axis(columns = None,index = 'dateresponded'))
print(new_df)
```

---

```
new_df = (df.groupby(df['date'].dt.to_period('Q'))
            .col1
            .value_counts()
            .unstack(fill_value = 0)
            .rename_axis(columns = None,index = 'dateresponded'))
 print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
               a  b  c
dateresponded         
2019Q4         0  1  1
2020Q1         2  1  0
```

Comment: thats it! beautiful implementation will accept the `crosstab` answer.